# Unable to cast object of type 'ASP._Page__ViewStart_cshtml' to type 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'. Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting the Unable to cast object of type

> ASP._Page__ViewStart_cshtml' to type 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'

when I run my MVC application.

Every answer I've found while searching tells me to make sure my ***_ViewStart*** file is in my ***Views*** folder, which it is. Even stranger is that I copied the exact same project files from my old Win 7 PC to my new Win 10 laptop. The application runs fine on the old PC but gets the above error on the new laptop. I'm also running both from Visual Studio 2015.

Any other ideas?

Full error message:

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP._Page__ViewStart_cshtml' to type 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'.]
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.GetStartPage(WebPageRenderingBase page, String fileName, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) +236
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +163
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +311
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +105
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765901
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Web Config in Views folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Utils" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.Export" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallbackPanel" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxMenu" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxNavBar" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxPopupControl" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxRoundPanel" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSplitter" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxTabControl" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeView" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpellChecker" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraCharts"/>
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraCharts.Web" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraReports" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraReports.UI" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.XtraReports.Web" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="DalManagerType" value="TimeTracker.DalEF.DalManager,TimeTracker.DalEF"/>
    <add key="DalManagerTypeFMS" value="FMSv3.DALEF.DalManager,FMSv3.DALEF" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />


    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: And what about if you add your code and the line which throws the exception?

Comment: You have a _ViewStart.cs file in your project root/Views folder and still getting this error? Make sure it didn't get dragged into a subfolder like Shared which could cause it not to be found.

Comment: Have you compared the versions of .Net between your machines?

Comment: Make sure that the build action is set to Content when looking to the file property.

Comment: Full error has been added to the original post. Yes, the _ViewStart.cshtml file is in root\Views folder. It's running under .net 4 on both machines.
Build action is set to Content.

Answer (score 0):

**case 1:**

It's `copy+paste` error when reorganizing your project.

Solution :  just remove `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`

**case 2:**

If you moved `_ViewStart.cshtml` away from the Views folder to the root folder of your project.

Solution : `_ViewStart.cshtml` files can only be placed into a Views folder. (at the same level as the `web.config`)

**case 3:**

If you upgraded MVC3 to the 4.5 framework and facing this error.

Solution : just add `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage` into `_ViewStart.cshtml`

Comment: All I have in that file is:

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Comment: what about of `Web.config` in view folder.@Nick

Comment: Added to original post.

Comment: `web.config` looks good. sorry another question is your `_ViewStart` location is `View-> _ViewStart`?@Nick

Comment: Yes, it's in the root of the Views folder.

Comment: @Nick try to put `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage` into `_ViewStart.cshtml`.